# How to integrate Rook Classes and httpuv

Tags: r, libuv, r-rook-package

I am trying to run some Rook Classes (such *Middleware*, *builder*, *Brewery* and *file*) with httpuv, knowing that web application is "implemented in accordance with the Rook specification." ( from httpuv documentation ).

However, it seems that not all Rook specifications are implemented in httpuv package.

Though Rook have web server (Rhttpd) , httpuv provide more preformance ( based on Libuv) and features such webSockets.

So, my question is did any one tried to use such mentioned classes with httpuv ?
Do any one knows site, blog, or any documentation that may help in such integration ?

what I know is loading the httpuv and Rook and running the httpuv server.

```
library(httpuv)
library(Rook)
webapp = list( onHeader = function(req) {... etc ...}, 
               call     = function(req) {... etc ...}, 
               onWSOpen = function(req) {... etc ...}
          )
runServer(host,port,webapp)
```

Now , how can I use and integrate Rook Classes (such *Middleware*, *builder*, *Brewery* and *file*) to compose **webapp** ?